# Macbook Air 2017 not turning on but momentarily gives power in usb on pressing power button

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, power

My Macbook Air 2017 has stopped working suddenly. When I press the power button, fans don't start and it stays dead.

Interesting thing to note is that if I attach a USB mouse to it and press the power button, the mouse lights up for half a second and then turns off.

It was working fine yesterday and I closed the lid with 100% battery. But today it refuses to turn on. At night, I kept the laptop on a table instead of keeping it inside a bag as usual.

It is raining season here and I suspect this might be due to humidity.

I have tried:

1. Clearing PRAM and SMC
2. Charging with the power adapter.
3. Pressing and holding the power button
4. Giving warm air using heater for 1-2 minutes to dry out moisture

Comment: No chime? What happens when you press the Option-key while turning it on?

Comment: @slartibartfast Nothing happens. There is no chime or display or keyboard light. Nothings happens when we press the Option-key while turning it on.